# Search String into NSArray based on charcters order?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, nsmutablearray

My Problem Scenario is like this. I have an NSMutableArray ( Every Object is Nsstring). I have a UItextField ( as Client said) for Search.

I want know how to Search String into NSMutableArray like this

if I type A into textfield only those Content come from NSMutableArray which start From A.
if I type AB into TextField only those Content Comes from NSMutableArray which is started from AB.. 
.... 
I am Trying NSRange Concept I like share Mycode

~

```
  for (int i=0; i<[[localTotalArrayForAwailable objectForKey:@"PUNCH"] count]; i++)
{

    NSString *drinkNamePuch= [[[localTotalArrayForAwailable objectForKey:@"PUNCH"]  objectAtIndex:i] drinkNames];

    NSRange titleResultsRange = [drinkNamePuch rangeOfString:searchText options:( NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];

    if (titleResultsRange.length>0)
    {
        [searchArraypuch addObject:[[localTotalArrayForAwailable objectForKey:@"PUNCH"]  objectAtIndex:i]];
        [copyListOfItems setValue:searchArraypuch forKey:@"PUNCH"];
    }
}
```

~

Based on this code search not working proper as i need.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use my two lines code? You don't need to iterate through your array to find stuffs!

Comment: BTW: From what I can derive, what you are doing, you should do `[copyListOfItems setValue:searchArraypuch forKey:@"PUNCH"];` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find all of the strings that match your `searchText` from the beginning, then you should check:

```
if ( titleresultsRange.location == 0 )
```

Other than that, I am not sure what is  "not working proper", you need to provide a better explanation of what your expected results are, and what your actual results are.

Comment: Suppose i want search only those which start ABC into NSMutableArray. If i using My code it's return all strings which have ABC ( No case Sensitive ) .. but I want only those which start with ABC . .. Example like :- Search into Database table with Like search query "ABC%.." something like search concept ..

Comment: @Mukesh try using my conditional above, instead of your check on the length.

Answer (score 1):

Do this;

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray* filteredStrings = [[localTotalArrayForAwailable objectForKey:@"PUNCH"]  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

In filteredStrings you got all the strings that begins with searchText.

You might find [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods, which are provided by NSArray/NSMutableArray:

1. In [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) see section "Finding Objects in an Array" for filtering methods starting with "indexesOfObjects...", e.g. [indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest%3a)
2. In [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) see section "Deriving New Arrays" for the method [filteredArrayUsingPredicate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a)
3. In [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) there is a method [filterUsingPredicate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/filterUsingPredicate%3a)

For narrowing the results you can continue applying the filtering consecutively to the filtered arrays or index sets.

---

Example with [indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest%3a) using a [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html):

```c
NSArray *strings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"a", @"aB", @"AbC", @"Bag", @"Babc", @"baCK", @"", @"dba", nil];
NSString *searchString = @"Ab";

BOOL (^startsWithPredicate)(id, NSUInteger, BOOL*) = ^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *string = (NSString *) obj;
    NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    return (range.location == 0);
};

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [strings indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:startsWithPredicate];
NSLog(@"Strings found: %@", [strings objectsAtIndexes:indexSet]);
```

Output:

```
Strings found: (
    aB,
    AbC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this logic....it is working

```
 NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aa",@"bbb",@"bb",@"cc",@"dd",@"ee",@"ff",@"gg",@"hh",@"ii", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrNew = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *strSearch = @"cccc";
int k = strSearch.length;
for (int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<k; j++) {
        if (k<=[[arr objectAtIndex:i] length]) {
            if ([strSearch characterAtIndex:j] != [[arr objectAtIndex:i]characterAtIndex:j]) {
                break;
            }
            else if(j == k-1){
                [arrNew addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
            }
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",[arrNew description]);
```